# Closed form for Euler sum with $H_{2n}$?.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation

I ran across this Euler sum while trying to evaluate an integral. I mentioned it in another thread, but though perhaps asking about it separate may be a good idea.

> Is there a closed form for this Euler sum? 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n}}{n(6n+1)}.$$

Numerically, it converges to around $0.502788$

I found that sum while trying to evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x^{3})\log(1-x^{3})dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(H_{n}-H_{2n}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)dx$$

I managed to obtain two of the sums. This is the only one giving me trouble.

It comes from the identity:

$$\log(1+x)\log(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(H_{n}-H_{2n}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)x^{2n}$$

Note that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{n(6n+1)}=1/4\left(-72+2\gamma^{2}+\pi^{2}+4\gamma\psi(1/6)+2\psi(1/6)-2\psi_{1}(7/6)\right)$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}(6n+1)}=3\sqrt{3}\pi+\zeta(2)+9\log(3)+12\log(2)-36.$$

I thought maybe the residue method would work, but I am not so sure.

By considering $f(z)=\frac{\pi cot(\pi z)(\gamma+\psi(-2z))}{z(6z+1)}$

The residue at the origin is $18-\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}$

The residue at $-1/6$ is $3\pi (\gamma+\psi(1/3))$

But, there does not appear to be a residue for the positive half integers.

The series for the positive integers is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{(z-n)^{2}}+\frac{H_{2n}}{z-n}+...$$

which gives a residue of :

$$\frac{-1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{12n+1}{n^{2}(6n+1)^{2}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n}}{n(6n+1)}+....=\frac{1}{2}\psi_{1}(7/6)-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}+H$$

At the negative integers:

$$\frac{H_{2n}}{z+n}+....$$

giving a residue of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n-1}}{n(6n+1)}$$

I do not think it quite adds up though. I could have easily went astray in all of that, though.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The question is (I guess) : is there a closed form for the sum ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Can anyone find a closed form for said Euler sum?.

Comment: I emended the heading to be more specific about what I was asking.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but what is $H_n$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a partial answer but I believe I am making progress. Let $S$ denote the sum. Then $$
\begin{align*}
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}}{n(6n+1)} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{n}\int_0^1 x^{6n}\; dx \\
&= \int_0^1\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{n}x^{6n}\right)dx \tag{1}\end{align*}
$$

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n}x^n$ where $|x|<1$. It can be shown that
$$f(x)=\text{Li}_2(x)+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-x) \tag{2}$$
Then, we can write
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{n}x^{6n} &= f(x^3)+f(-x^3) \\
&= \text{Li}_2(x^3)+\text{Li}_2(-x^3)+\frac{\log^2(1-x^3)+\log^2(1+x^3)}{2}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
$$
Substitute (3) into (1) to get
$$
\begin{align*}
S=\int_0^1 \left(\text{Li}_2(x^3)+\text{Li}_2(-x^3)+\frac{\log^2(1-x^3)+\log^2(1+x^3)}{2} \right) dx \tag{4}
\end{align*}
$$
Note that
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\left( \text{Li}_2(x^3)+\text{Li}_2(-x^3)\right)dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{6n}}{n^2} \; dx \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2(6n+1)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{6}{n}+\frac{36}{1+6n} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} -6\psi_0\left(\frac{1}{6} \right)-6\gamma_0-36\right) \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{3\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}+6\log 2+\frac{9}{2}\log 3-18 \tag{5}
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\log^3(1-x^3)dx &= \frac{1}{6}\int_0^1t^{-2/3}\log^2(1-t)dt \quad (t=x^3)\\
&= \frac{1}{6}\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} B(x,y)\right]_{x=1/3,y=1} \\
&= \frac{\pi ^2}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}+\frac{9}{2}+\frac{9}{8} \log^2 3-\frac{9 \log 3}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3} \pi  \log 3-\frac{\psi_1\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{2}\tag{6}
\end{align*}
$$
Substitute (5) and (6) into equation (4) to get
$$S=-\frac{27}{2}+\frac{5\pi^2}{24}+\frac{9}{8}\log^2 3+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{4}(4+\log 3)+6\log 2-\frac{1}{2}\psi_1\left(\frac{4}{3} \right)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \log^2(1+x^3)dx \tag{7}$$

Now, it remains to calculate $\int_0^1\log^2(1+x^3)dx$.

**ADDED**

Use integration by parts,
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\log^2(1+x^3) dx &= \left[x\log^2(1+x^3) \right]_0^1-6\int_0^1 \frac{x^3\log(1+x^3)}{1+x^3}dx \\
&= \log^2 2-6 \int_0^1 \log(1+x^3)dx +6\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x^3)}{1+x^3}dx\tag{8}
\end{align*}
$$
The first integral is "elementary":
$$\int_0^1\log(1+x^3)dx = -3+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}+2\log 2 \tag{9}$$

Evaluating $\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x^3)}{1+x^3}$ is more tedious. Let $\omega=e^{i\pi /3}$. Then note that $1+x^3=(x+1)(x-\omega)(x-\bar{\omega})$ and

$$\frac{1}{1+x^3}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1+\bar{\omega}}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{x-\omega}-\frac{1+\omega}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{x-\bar{\omega}}$$

Expanding the logarithms and using the above partial fraction decomposition in $\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x^3)}{1+x^3}$ will result in 9 pieces which can be evaluated in terms of dilogarithms. Ultimately, all this will give a closed form for $\int_0^1 \log^2(1+x^3)dx$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{n(6n+1)}$.

Comment: according to Mathematica, that last integral equals $18-\frac{5}{36}\pi^2+\frac{\log^23}{4}+(\log2-4)\log8+\frac{\log\frac{2187}{16}-12}{2\sqrt{3}}\pi+\text{Li}_2(-1/3)-(1+i\sqrt{3})\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{3-i \sqrt{3}}{6}\right)$

$+(1-i\sqrt{3})\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{3-i\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)-(1-i\sqrt{3})\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{3+i\sqrt{3}}{6}\right)+(1+i\sqrt{3})\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{3+ i \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)=0.0837342\dots$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Great! Now we have the closed form for the sum.

Comment: Wow, look at you I&S!. It is surprising and cool to see a reply to this problem after all this time. I had forgotten about this sum. Nice indeed.  btw...Shobit...is that you?.  That is one wacky result Mathematica gave. Maybe it can be simplified.

Comment: @Cody: Yes, that is me.

Comment: Wow, dude, where ya' been?. Good to hear from you. Good work!

Comment: @Cody: I am planning to come back very soon. The site has been almost dead, it seems.

Comment: Yes, folks would very much like that. Many have wondered what happened. Maybe we can revive things. :) See ya' around soon.